# Using automotive R134A in my refrigerator?

Tags: air-conditioning, refrigerator

Can I use automotive R134A in my refrigerator without damaging anything?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the thread on the automotive is different, they made the change to prevent shop mechanics from using the wrong type of Freon. Both auto and hvac r134 are chemically the same. I can usually find the automotive 134 a bit cheaper but legally it requires a licence. This sounds crazy when you think that air horns, freeze spray and canned air dusters are r134 but to put in an AC system it requires a license where all those other uses just dump Freon in the atmosphere but that is the law.